# Copy many formulas from one workbook to another without pasting in reference workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sheet like below. I want to copy all formulas from workbook B into A but without the reference to workbook B.

when I do it now I currently get a link in all my formulas to workbook B. But I want just the formulas but linked to my current workbook (workbook a)

If I copy a basic sum formula it works but when the formula involves a table, the reference is to workbook B.

here is a sample formula,

`=IF(Start!$D$8="Weekly",0.000001*SUMIFS(tbl_database[Value],tbl_database[Node],H$2,tbl_database[Type],$A14,tbl_database[Accounting],$C$1,tbl_database[Filter],"No"),0.000001*SUMIFS(tbl_database[Value],tbl_database[Node],H$2,tbl_database[Type],$A14,tbl_database[Accounting],$C$1,tbl_database[Source],"<>stack",tbl_database[Source],"<>overflow"))`

workbook A Sheet a:

[image]

workbook B sheet B

[image]

if I go to the formula bar and copy the actual formula from workbook B into A, I get the expected result, but as you can see with all these formulas, it can be tedious.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Clearly you and I are doing something differently, I just wonder what. Could you please, show one simple formula that exposes the problem?

Comment: Have you tried Paste Special -> Formulas?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad , yes I have tried, it still references workbook B. Which I don't want. I want to just paste the formulas itself and have it reference the current workbook.

Comment: @TomBrunberg ,  I got some more info. If I copy a cell with a `SUM` , but formulas from workbook B that reference a table, I get the reference to workbook B.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I still can not reproduce. Please copy - paste a single formula from a cell in your workbook B to the text of your post

Comment: @TomBrunberg okay i have tried give a formula, i changed some of the actual column names for simplicity.

Comment: A single Find+Replace action *after* pasting can resolve this issue.

Comment: @David, good idea.. replace the reference workbook name with blank you mean? However the reference workbook can be referenced in different formats ie [workbook] , 'workbook'!, etc. which is also annoying

Comment: How about : press `ctrl + (grave accent symbol)` (to show formulatext)** , select all, copy to notepad or notepad++, then find & replace the sheet name.  || **you may also use `=formulatext()` on an extra sheet to get the formulas.

Comment: Tell me in Sheet 1 you need Only Formula or both Formula & Value ☺

Comment: Let me tell you the most easiest method to copy Formula along with Data from One to other Sheet, Press `Ctrl+~ ` excel will display Formula in cells , press `Ctrl+A`,  then `Ctrl+C` next move to destination Sheet  & `Paste`. If You need only VALUES the use `Paste Special` & `Values` option ☺

Comment: If you are comfortable with Macro the I can suggest you a simple one  **to copy all formulas from one sheet to another**  ☺

Comment: @RajeshS I need formula, not value. I tried tried your `Ctrl+~` but I still get the references to workbook b. Do I need to close that workbook? Macro could work too.

Comment: @excelguy I see you have added a formula in your question, can you add what this formula should look like *after* it's been pasted?

Comment: @excelguy, principally when you Copy & Paste formula Excel pulls both Value as well as Formula. And this happens in case of VBA also.  Suppose you write this, `Range("C19").Select`
 `Selection.Copy`
`Range("F20").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas`
will copy the formula & the Value Both.

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Excel 2010

Copying any portion of the table from A to B will reference back to A.  Copying the entire table (must include the headers!) does not reference back to A - unless the formula has a reference to a different table or a different sheet.  Formulas in the table that reference a range outside the table but on the same sheet will properly reference B.

A solution (albeit not a very good one) is to ensure the table does not have any formulas that reference another table or sheet before copying to B.  You could do this by migrating your data in A to the same sheet.

As mentioned in the comments using `Ctrl H` to find all references to the sheet and replace with a nullstring is a quick way to resolve the issue after pasting.

Not mentioned in the comments is the possibility of named ranges  pointing back to A, quite likely with broken links.  You can try to mitigate this by using worksheet scope (opposed to workbook) but it is likely you'll still need to edit/delete them in the name manager after pasting into B.

I'm keen on VBA and believe the best solution is to write the code that generates the original report in A. This would remove the requirement of copying from A to B, simply run the program to generate a new report as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant but . . . . why not allow the references to copy across and then use edit/replace to remove them all?